# DynamicRows (or Associative Array) in Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, ui-form

I am using Magento 2 REST API for the mobile application. I am facing some complexity so I need your help.

I have DynamicRows component with two fields in UI Form, the name of the field is *localization*.

```
<container name="localization" sortOrder="9" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/templates/default</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Data</item>
            <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
            <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add Parameter</item>
            <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <container name="record">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true" />
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="option_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parameter</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_label</item>
                    <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_value">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Value</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_value</item>
                    <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cirklestudio_color_picker" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <actionDelete>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" />
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionDelete>
        
    </container>

</container>
```

The output of the DynamicRows is below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 
            [option_label] => tmp_dir
            [option_value] => temp
            [position] => 1
            [record_id] => 0
            [initialize] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 1
            [row_id] => 
            [option_label] => main_dir
            [option_value] => APD
            [position] => 2
            [initialize] => true
        )
)
```

I have declared a method getLocalization() in my Interface

```
/**
 * Return localized parameters for the application
 *
 * @return mixed[]
 */
public function getLocalization();
```

Then I have implemented the method

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getLocalization()
{
    // Unserialize array
    $data = $this->_getData('localization') ? unserialize($this->_getData('localization')) : "";


    $output = [];
    foreach ($data as $param) {
        $output[$param['option_label']] =  $param['option_value'];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

In the above method, I have refined the DynamicRows array output as per the requirements.

```
Array
(
    [tmp_dir] => temp
    [main_dir] => APD
)
```

When I hit the REST API endpoint, I get the following response.

```
<localization>
    <item>temp</item>
    <item>APD</item>
</localization>
```

Whereas I expect the following response

```
<localization>
    <tmp_dir>temp</tmp_dir>
    <main_dir>APD</main_dir>
</localization>
```

I have searched around different articles but couldn't find the best answer to suit my requirements.

> **Question:** How I will get my expected result keeping this thing in mind that DynamicRows data will not be always the same, might be another record has more than two fields with different **option_label** and **option_value**?

Comment: is it possible to put more code? more of the uicomponents would be helpful..

Comment: In Ui Component there is only a single DynamicRow field/container, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to come up to the following:

[image]

I think you will struggle to get more from it. Basically, the item keys do come from Magento core parsing method so that your result comes to you as an xml.

I can detail my steps but it does amount to 2 more interfaces and a bit of parsing.. Do let me know if this output is something you could compromise with.

Joseph's answer is simpler than mine (more elegant). But below is the core from my solution. I also put a link to the bitbucket repository for you to try out by yourself. `https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/apiparser/src/master/`

```
    $output = [];
            foreach ($data as $param) {
                $output[$param['option_label']] =  $param['option_value'];
            }
    
            return $this->parsedDataInterfaceFactory->create([
                'itemsData' => $output
            ]);


class ParsedResult implements ParsedDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Mbs\Calculator\Api\Data\ParsedDataItemInterface[]
     */
    private $items = [];

    /**
     * OperationResult constructor.
     * @param array $itemsData
     * @param \Mbs\Calculator\Api\Data\ParsedDataItemInterfaceFactory $dataItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        $itemsData,
        \Mbs\Calculator\Api\Data\ParsedDataItemInterfaceFactory $dataItemInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        foreach ($itemsData as $itemLabel => $itemValue) {
            $this->items[] = $dataItemInterfaceFactory->create([
                'label' => $itemLabel,
                'value' => $itemValue
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \Mbs\Calculator\Api\Data\ParsedDataItemInterface[]
     */
    public function getLocalization()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}

class Item implements ParsedDataItemInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $label,
        string $value
    ) {
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I think I can manage such output. I am waiting for your detailed answer.

Comment: Wow, amazing logic, thanks a ton mate. You said that Joseph answer is more elegant, is this possible to elaborate his answer? Once again, thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: if you use josepth's code and directly use the interface \Mbs\Calculator\Api\Data\ParsedDataItemInterface, you'll get the same result as mine.. But be careful, the interfaces annotations need updating and that is a big part of this work.. can you accept btw, aby little point counts

Comment: Thanks once again @Herve, I really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: I am sure you understand we all like good questions.. this was really interesting even though I had a few sweats for it. thank you indeed

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy can you please look into this, Thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/332953/77554

Answer (score 2):

**To get the desired result, you need to create more classes.**

In this case, `getLocalization` should return an instance of a class, like:

```
/**
 * @return \MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Localization[]
 **/
public function getLocalization(): array
{
    // Unserialize array
    $data = $this->_getData('localization') ? unserialize($this->_getData('localization')) : "";

    return array_map(function($option) {
        return $this->localizationFactory->create([
            'label' => $param['option_label'],
            'value' => $param['option_value']
        ]);
    });
}
```

Where `$this->localizationFactory` is: `\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\LocalizationFactory`.

`LocalizationFactory` should have two methods:

- `getLabel`
- `getValue`

This might seem verbose, and it is. However, this route gives you 100% control over the output. Testability is a bonus.

Comment: Do you mean mapper classes? Like I have to map my output to another class? The factory class is usually used to fetch data from the database/table. How I will be able to map such a class over my output? I shall be very thankful if you can further elaborate on the class.